# How to do query on multiple dates on certain range on Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing quite long query to find a customer with certain condition on certain dates, in this case `'2019-6-20'`, the query is like this

Here's my code

```
select current_date() as date , count(customer_id) as cell13
from(
select customer_id, count(id) as total, string_agg(payment_state order by created_at desc limit 1) as cek
from(
select distinct(A.id), A.customer_id, extract(month from A.created_at) as months,extract(day from A.created_at) as days, extract(year from A.created_at) as years, payment_state, A.created_at, A.grandtotal_cents
from bl.orders as A
left join bl.blacklists as B
on A.customer_id = B.customer_id
where date(A.created_at) >= date_sub(date('2019-6-20') , interval 60 day) and grandtotal_cents > 0 and B.customer_id is null
)
group by customer_id
having cek = "unpaid")
```

Here's the result

```
Row  date          cell13
1    2019-06-21    696
```

Now I need to query this to multiple dates in certain date range, for example `2019-03-23` to `2019-06-21`. How suppose I do this, so the output will like

```
Row  date          cell13
1    2019-06-21    696
...
90   2019-03-23    ...
```

Comment: the query you presented cannot produce claimed result - please double check and present correct one so we can adjust it to work for range of dates. also provide some sample data and expected result (as you did in your previous question)

Comment: I should do this later

Comment: sure, at least query now looks reasonable - i will get back to it in the morning, unless someone will already answer it by that time :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a table of dates using `generate_date_array()` and `unnest()` and then use this with a `left join`.

Overall, though, your query is a message an hard to follow, but here is the idea:

```
with dates as (
      select dte
      from (select generate_date_array('2019-03-23', '2016-06-21', interval 1 day) d
           ) d cross join
           unnest(d.d) dte
     )
select . . .
from dates left join
     bl.orders o
     on date(o.created_at) >= date_sub(dte, interval 60 day)
     . . .
```